# Darboux's theorem in other words

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a $2n$-dimensional symplectic manifold.
The claim of Darboux's theorem is that for any point $p\in M$, there exists a local coordinate $(U;q^1,...,q^n,p_1,...,p_n)$, and on $U$, the symplectic form $\omega$ can be written in the form $\omega|_U = dq^i \wedge dp_i$.

I have learned that Darboux's theorem can be paraphrased as follows:
For any points $p\in M, p'\in M'$ in two symplectic manifolds $(M,\omega),(M',\omega')$ of equal dimension, there exists open sets $U, U'$ containing $p,p'$ respectively, and a homomorphic map $\phi : U \rightarrow U'$, satisfying $\phi(p) = p'$ and the pull back $\phi^*\omega' = \omega$.

However, I have tried to think of the proof that the two claims are equivalent, but I can't come up with it, nor have I found books with the proof. Could you please give me the proof or let me know the book where the proof is written?

Comment: The key is to think of the first statement as there locally exists a map $\phi:U\to V\subset \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ which preserves the standard symplectic form on $\mathbb{R} ^{2n}$ (this is the coordinate patch).

Comment: You mean a diffeomorphism $\phi$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer expands on @J.V.Gaiter's comment.
Let $\varphi\colon U \subset \Bbb R^{2n} \to \varphi(U) \subset M$ and $\varphi' \colon U' \subset \Bbb R^{2n} \to \varphi'(U')\subset M'$ be Darboux charts centred at $0$ for $(M,\omega)$ and $(M',\omega')$ respectively.
This means that
$$
(\varphi^*\omega)|_U = {\omega_0}|_U
$$
and
$$
((\varphi')^*\omega')|_{U'} = {\omega_0}|_{U'}
$$
where $\omega_0 = \sum_{j=1}^n dx_j\wedge dy_j$ on $\Bbb R^{2n}$ with coordinates $(x_1,y_1,\ldots,x_n,y_n)$.
This is precisely the statement of Darboux Theorem applied to $(M,\omega)$ and $(M',\omega')$.
Then $(\varphi^*\omega)|_{U\cap U'} = ((\varphi')^*\omega')|_{U\cap U'}$.
Notice that
$$
\psi =\varphi'\circ \varphi^{-1} \colon \varphi(U\cap U')\subset M \to \varphi'(U\cap U') \subset M'
$$
is a diffeomorphism between open subsets of $M$ and $M'$, such that
$
\psi^*( \omega'|_{\varphi'(U\cap U')}) = \omega|_{\varphi(U\cap U')}.
$

In other words, all $2n$-dimensional symplectic manifolds are locally symplectomorphic.
This in particular rules out the existence of local invariants for symplectic geometry.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. The reason why both $U$ and $U'$ contain $0$(possible by translation) is to make sure that the intersection of $U$ and $U'$ is not an empty set?

Comment: @tony-c exactly